# Rewrite Rule to Ignore/Strip Certain Parameter

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

I am doing a number of URL rewrites and I have a some URL patterns where I would rather strip one of the params or ignore it when running the rule.

for example:

> http://domain.com/page.php?name=Something Really & Bad&id=12

In this example I would like to strip or ignore the name parameter and just focus on the id parameter, it would also cut down some of my rules because there are some links coming it with just the id in them and no name.

Currently this is what I have and it works except on those with spaces or special characters.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=SOMETHING&cat=11$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^products\.php$ http://www.domain.com/anotherpage.html? [R=301,L]
```